# QGIS Symbology changes by number value

Tags: qgis, symbology

I've gotten a state file with count outlines joined to an attribute file that shows numbers of items per county. ArcGIS has the ability to set the symbology to grade the results into pre-determined results, such as 0-10, 11-20 and so forth. Can QGIS do this without having to go through the tedious advanced query of getting all the 0-10, 11-19, 20-29 and create them into separate v-layers. It would seem that a one stop progression that would be set up in symbology or somewhere else would be more useful.

Comment: Did you look at the style tab?

Comment: I did look at the style tab. I was going to write that the Mac version appears not to have the same style window layout, but I looked again and it has changed to a graduated fill. Will have to experiment more.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for the **Graduated** renderer. Here's the manual: http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/html/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#style-tab

[image]